# ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application for Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, python-2.x

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 24, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.artist as martist
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 8, in <module>
    from transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, \
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 35, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I am getting this error.
I have tried `activepython`, `python xy`, but the error still persists.

Comment: Where did you install Matplotlib from?

Comment: You can still try [WinPython](http://winpython.github.io/) and [Enthought](https://www.enthought.com/products/epd/) that you haven't tried. But the distribution should make little difference. You're going to need to give us details about your system and what it is you do _exactly_.

Answer (score 12):

The error that you are getting is because you have installed the wrong component of `matplotlib` **(`there are the 32 bit and 64 bit components`).**

[This page provides you all binaries (32bit,64bit) for Windows.](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) It also includes other packages apart from matplotlib if you may be needing them in the future.

Try installing the proper version for your computer and it should work.

**Also don't forget to check whether the Python version you are using is suitable for your computer (32bit or 64bit)**

So the problem you are facing is one of these:

- You have a 32 bit system, but you have installed the 64 bit component of `matplotlib`
- You have a 64 bit system, but you have installed the 32 bit component of `matplotlib`
- You have a 32 bit system, but you have installed the 64 bit component of `Python` itself
- You have a 64 bit system, but you have installed the 32 but component of `Python` itself

If you are not sure about how your computer's processor handles information, please check [THIS WEBSITE](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows7/find-out-32-or-64-bit)

To check which version of python you have installed, refer [TO THIS QUESTION IN STACKOVERFLOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os)

Comment: I had 2 versions of python 32 and 64 bits, I had to remove the 64 bits (on win 64)

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to ThePredator answer:

I had **both** 32 bit and 64 bit Python 2.7 installed. When I ran python from cmd, Windows would load 32 bit python, but when trying to run something with matplotlib, this error would pop up. I have a 64 bit machine

**What I did to solve**

1. Uninstall all python versions (check within Control Panel -> Programs and Resources)
2. Install coherent versions for python ant matplotlib (32 bit python should go with 32 bit matplotlib, etc.). Most recent Python installers come with `pip`, so make sure Python directory is in your PATH AND just enter **`pip install matplotlib`** in a command prompt and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

On jupyter notebook I solved this problem by this way:

1. Install "numpy-1.11.0b2+mkl-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl" from [this page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy).
2. If there is still no change, it's worth trying to reinstall matplotlib by pip.