# Python import failing due to 32bit

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have installed the 64bit Python environment (verified from console that it is 64 bit):

```
Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:24:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

The error I am getting is when calling the line

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and the error is

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is no valid Win32-application.
```

Now the matploblib I installed was from a file named `matplotlib-1.5.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` and should be the 64bit version of the library. How can I narrow down what's going on here?

I downloaded the whl itself from `http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/`

Edit: The whole error message

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 114, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 6, in <module>
    from matplotlib.externals.six.moves import tkinter as Tk
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\externals\six.py", line 199, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\externals\six.py", line 113, in
 _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\externals\six.py", line 80, in
_import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 38, in <module>
    import FixTk
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\FixTk.py", line 68, in <module>
    import _tkinter
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 ist keine zulõssige Win32-Anwendung.
```

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638621/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-for-python-mat

Comment: I did check that SO question, but verified everything on there, so that should not be it.

Comment: From the complete error message (just added) it seems to point to _tkinter, but I checked the .pyd with DependencyWalker, and its 64bit

Comment: Possibly your 64 bit `matplotlib` is finding a 32 bit `_tkinter` somewhere else on your path.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the two DLLs in my Python/DLLs were 32bit, no idea why, but that fixed it.